# How to use multiple config for nicEditor?

Tags: javascript, nicedit

I have a textarea with id "`p_1_input`", as you can see below, I am trying to limit the functions of this editor dialog and also limit its height so excessive content won't push the dialog extend but scrollable.
 How can I put the two config in online such as:
"`{maxHeight : 200}" and "{buttonList : ['bold','italic']}`"?

```
new nicEditor({buttonList : ['bold','italic']}).panelInstance('p_1_input');
new nicEditor({maxHeight : 200}).panelInstance('p_1_input');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this.

```
new nicEditor({
         maxHeight: 133,
         buttonList: ['bold','italic']
          }).panelInstance('p_1_input');
```